# A dependency job for cockpit.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details

Tags: 20.04, cockpit

I've just installed cockpit on Lubuntu 20.04 LTS, but when I run it I get this error:

```
A dependency job for cockpit.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
```

Running journalctl -xe gives the output below. Any ideas for how to diagnose/fix this?

```
myuser@HP-MICROSERVER:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo mkdir cockpit.socket.d && cd cockpit.socket.d
myuser@HP-MICROSERVER:/etc/systemd/system/cockpit.socket.d$ sudo featherpad listen.conf
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
myuser@HP-MICROSERVER:/etc/systemd/system/cockpit.socket.d$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
myuser@HP-MICROSERVER:/etc/systemd/system/cockpit.socket.d$ sudo systemctl restart cockpit.socket
Job failed. See "journalctl -xe" for details.
myuser@HP-MICROSERVER:/etc/systemd/system/cockpit.socket.d$ sudo systemctl start cockpit
A dependency job for cockpit.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
myuser@HP-MICROSERVER:/etc/systemd/system/cockpit.socket.d$ journalctl -xe
-- The job identifier is 58327 and the job result is failed.
Feb 20 14:52:57 HP-MICROSERVER systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Cockpit Web Service.
-- Subject: A start job for unit cockpit.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit cockpit.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 58200 and the job result is dependency.
Feb 20 14:52:57 HP-MICROSERVER systemd[1]: cockpit.service: Job cockpit.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Feb 20 14:52:57 HP-MICROSERVER systemd[1]: Starting Cockpit motd updater service...
-- Subject: A start job for unit cockpit-motd.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit cockpit-motd.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 58328.
Feb 20 14:52:57 HP-MICROSERVER systemd[1]: cockpit-motd.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit cockpit-motd.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Feb 20 14:52:57 HP-MICROSERVER systemd[1]: Finished Cockpit motd updater service.
-- Subject: A start job for unit cockpit-motd.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit cockpit-motd.service has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 58328.
```